# com.facebook.sdk error 2 only on Ad Hoc Distribution

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

We are using Facebook SDK 3.1 .  Deployment target is iOS5.1.

App runs fine in Debugging mode on both simulator and device (iPhone 5).  The user can post to his/her own wall.  But when the user tries to post using the Ad Hoc Distribution version, the error message - com.facebook.sdk error:2 pops up after clicking OK on App would like to post publicly on your behalf pop up window.

The app bundle ID is set in the Facebook App page and matches that in the iPhone app.

We request the publishing permission the first time and not the read permission first and then ask for reauthorization later.  Since it works fine on the simulator and the iPhone 5 when in Debugging mode, we would assume it should work in the Ad Hoc Distribution version.

Did we miss something?  The error keeps on appearing.

Any help is appreciated!

aobs

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was that I wasn't using the correct identifier in the facebook settings. Xcode used different identifiers for each build type.